# How do I downgrade runc using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am writing an ansible script to help facilitate my deployment.

In my ec2 instance, i manually ran this command `sudo yum downgrade runc`.

Before i ran this command. runc --version return `runc version 1.0.0-rc10`

After i ran this command. runc --version return `runc version 1.0.0-rc6+dev`

How do I get the same thing in ansible?

What i try:

```
- name: Downgrade runc version to 1.0.0-rc6+dev
  yum:
    name: runc-1.0.0-rc6
    state: latest
    allow_downgrade: true
```

Comment: What is the problem with your task above? Do you get any error? What's the result? How does it differ from your expectation? And why don't you use the exact name-version in your task? => `runc-1.0.0-rc6+dev`

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!  The `state: latest` is installing the *latest* version of the package.  Instead of that, you'll want `state: present`.  The distinction is noted in their [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_module.html):

> `present` and installed will simply ensure that a desired package is installed.

> `latest` will update the specified package if it's not of the latest available version.
> So, try:

```
- name: Downgrade runc version to 1.0.0-rc6+dev
  yum:
    name: runc-1.0.0-rc6
    state: present
    allow_downgrade: true
```